# Deleting Row from UITableView changes information stored in other rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, nsindexpath

Let's say there are 10 rows in my `UITableView`, each with its own unique information, and I delete row 4. After the action is completed, row 5 becomes row 4, row 6 becomes row 5, and so on. Well, Row 5 loads the data that was in row 4 before being deleted. How can I just delete the information that was in row 4 entirely so that row 5 doesn't become row 4. By the way, my `UITableView` consists of custom cells with multiple `UITextField's`- just so you know. I'm just brainstorming and any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove that row's data from array which you used to fill table.

Answer (score 3):

On deleting a row and removing the data object from your datasource, the `UITableView` on reload or update WILL move the rows up for the updated datasource. If you want to keep the deleted row blank visually, you could delete the data object and set a flag in its place, a `BOOL` for instance, as a placeholder in the datasource. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you could check for this `Boolean` flag and display an empty `UITableViewCell`.